# Ошибка с чтением-записью Java

Tags: java, исключения

```
public static void ReadWorkingList()
{
        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\Working"));
        while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
        }
}
public static void WorkingDelete() throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\Working"));
    DataOutputStream outWrite = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("E:\\tmp"));
    while (in.available()>0)
    {
        System.out.println(in.readUTF());
    }
    System.out.println("Введите имя человека, которого нужно удалить");
    String deleteName = read.readLine();
    while (in.available()>0)
    {
        String tmp = in.readUTF();
        if(tmp.equals(deleteName))//сравнение введённого имени со строками в файле, если есть такое, то след.итерация.
        {
            continue;
        }
        outWrite.writeUTF(tmp);
    }
    //запись из файла TMP в файл
    DataInputStream outTMPinWorkList = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\tmp"));
    DataOutputStream WriteList = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("E:\\Working"));
    while (outTMPinWorkList.available()>0)
    {
        WriteList.writeChars(outTMPinWorkList.readUTF()); // Запись из одного файла в другой
    }
    outTMPinWorkList.close();
    WriteList.close();
    read.close();
    in.close();
    outWrite.close();

}
```

Подскажите, почему вылетает EOFEexception? Почему он не успевает считать?
 И почему WorkingDelete ничего не записывает в файл tmp? Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: попробуйте закрывать пишущий поток перед тем, как открывать файл по новой для чтения (`outWrite.close()`).

Comment: А из-за чего может вылетать такой эксепшен EOFExcpetion? Например в таком коде " DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\Working"));
            System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());" Файл не пустой, есть данные

Comment: какие данные? можете строку и hex-заголовок показать? в начале файла случаем нет EOF байта?

Comment: Читаю текстовый файл, в файле обычная строка с кириллицей, хочу её вывести в консоль, а вылетает эксепшен. И как-то раз через раз он вылетает. При, допустим, смене файла с "Working" на, например "Working1" - первое время всё нормально, а потом начинается снова эта муть

Comment: вы не написали, в какой строке оно вылетает, но попробую угадать по внутренностям жертвенной документации. Методы [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) выбрасывают EOF, если поток закончился раньше, чем они смогли прочитать достаточно байт для для завершения, что может быть, если файл не дописан на диск, например. Но у вас есть еще другая ошибка: `writeChars` пишет не в том формате, который ожидает `readUTF`, после первого запуска программа записывает в `E:\Working` содержимое, которое не может прочесть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка java.io.EOFException у вас выскакивает из-за readUTF, данный метод не предназначен для чтения простого текста.

Там первые два байта - длина текста, потом идёт текст.

Попробуйте записать текст так:

```
try (DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\1.txt"))) {
    outputStream.writeUTF("test");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

В файл запишется  00 04 74 65 73 74 (это в шестнадцатеричном виде).

И из этого файла уже получится прочитать текст с помощью readUTF.

А когда вы читаете простой текстовый файл, то readUTF интепретирует первые два символа (байта) как длину, получает большое число и естественно не может прочитать.

Для чтения простого текстового файла используйте BufferedReader

Comment: Безумно благодарен вам, бился несколько часов над этим, и не заметил где сам себе понаставлял костыли:)